# Is there a way to calculate the number of tries X, who's binomial probability falls on given number CPR? (example inside)

Tags: math, statistics

Let's assume we have an event with:

1. number of tries => `N = 20`
2. probability of success => `p = 0.3`
3. number of successes => `X = 0`
4. Probability that the event succeeds X number of times => `PR = 0.0007979` (check [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for how the calculation works)

So for X=0-20 we will have different probabilities where `PR(X=0) + PR(X=1) + ... + PR(X=20) = 1`

Now what I would like to do is generate a random number with regards to the binomial distributions X<sub>n</sub>, but without calculating all the specific Probabilities PR(X=0), PR(X=1), etc.

So how I've thought to solve this problem is to generate a random number from 0-1 and check where in this binomial distribution it falls

I.e. Suppose we have (as defined above):

1. `N = 20`
2. `p = 0.3`
3. `X = ?`
4. `Random number = CumulativePR = 0.6`

My question is: Is there a way to calculate 'm' for which the sum of previous probabilities falls

- `PR(X=0) + PR(X=1) ... + PR(X=m-1) < CumulativePR` and
- `PR(X=0) + PR(X=1) ... + PR(X=m) > CumulativePR`

Comment: I've not (yet) voted to close this question, but it's not clear to me that it has a programming component to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the so-called rejection method to sample from a binomial distribution. In that method, it's not necessary to calculate the cumulative probabilities. See for example Section 7.3 of "[Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html)" and doubtless many other references. I assume that you can translate the algorithm from C to whatever you want.

Chances are good that there is a library which already contains a sampling algorithm -- what programming language are you working with? Is it important for you to implement the algorithm yourself?